Why Java's int division rounds to zero?
I've found that the rule for rounding two int in Java is to get the value closer to 0.
Which mean that if you divide two positive numbers, you get the "floor" value e.g 7/3=2.
And if you divide one negative value by a positive one (or vice versa), you get the "ceiling" value: -7/3 = -2.
I would expect to be either both floor or ceiling value.

Is it because the "negative" is evaluated after the division ?

It it some legacy over C ?

Is it to stay consistant with some transitive operation of the remainder (% operator) ?
(i.e (a+(a%b)/b = ceiling(a/b) and (a-(a%b)/b = floor(a/b) )



One of the comment has the definitive answer I was looking for: it is specified in Java's official documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se23/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2-200

Integer division rounds toward 0.


As a lot of people also commented: it most likely comes from C, which comes from CPU implementation of integer division.
The C norm is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3604984/5190019 and it also says that C did it that way because Fortran also did.
The linked question ( Why do integer div and mod round towards zero?) explains how usual division with negative number occurs: division is made as if both number were positive, then it's transformed to the equivalent negative number.
Originally, it certainly comes from the easiest way to perform integer division with a CPU (with negative numbers using "two's complement" representation).

This question may be more approriate for "retrocomputing". But AFAIK CPUs of the Intel world have traditionally been implemented to perform "integer division towards 0", so it's probably from there.

Rounding would imply that it would even calculate results after the decimal and then discard that. It doesn't, the calculation stops at the least significant integral digit. That results in a truncated result, which looks like rounding to zero.

Note that % is not the modulo operator. It is a common mistake to think of it as modulo. It's actually the remainder operator.

"We round by lopping off the decimals" is just as consistent as "we round up" and "we round down". So, your expectations are in that sense bizarre. Perhaps your expectations are best stated as "I expect it would be something simple to somebody wearing the hat of a mathematician" but CPU design and informatics doesn't quite work that way generally. The specific answer goes via 'legacy over C' towards 'CPU designs of yore all did it this way'. Why did CPU designs do it that way? I don't know. I'm not positive there's a conclusive answer available to that question at all.

as specified in Java Language Specification 15.17.2. Division Operator /: "Integer division rounds toward 0. ..."

Yes, it is all legacy from C (and from long before Intel CPUs, I believe).

@rzwitserloot you're right, my expectations were pretty much from a mathematical point of view. As for C, someone in the other SO question says it wasn't until C99 that "reliable integer division" was defined; before, the behavior would be left to the implementation.

@Asoub and 'left to the implementation' is effectively short for 'whatever the fastest possible way to do this operation on modern hardware that fulfills the few things that you do have to guarantee as per C spec', i.e., that ends up being short for 'whatever the processors can do fastest'. Then java decided to eliminate as much ambiguity from specs as possible (until they ran into an issue with threading, and thus the JMM is filled to the rafters with the same kind of 'up to the implementation' text). So, what really happened, is that C/CPU design has encoded that rounding behaviour.

Nobody sane is going to now design a CPU instruction set where the integer rounding ops round in any way other than 'lop off the fraction'.

It doesn't actually round.  It just drops the fraction.
